# modifying LatestBlogPosts Umbraco 8

Tags: image, razor, datetimepicker, umbraco8

I am stumped I have been trying for hours to modify the lastestblogposts and keep hitting errors.  I want to do two things change the DateTime to the date piker so the user can choose the publish date displayed and secondly add an image.  the snippet I need to edit is here for the date my property is called date and for the image it's listingImage.  I have tried item.date.toString() and some others.  Thanks in advance for your help

```
if (pagedBlogposts.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="blogposts">

        @foreach (ContentModels.Blogpost post in pagedBlogposts)
        {
            <a href="@post.Url" class="blogpost">
              <h3 class="blogpost-title">@post.PageTitle</h3>

            </a>
                    <small class="blogpost-date">@post.date.ToString()</small>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>@post.Excerpt</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">

                </div>

}    }
            </div>


        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise I was creating a new editor in document type rather than using existing ones.  Once I swapped this over it was as simple as @post.PostImage.Url and @post.PostDate.ToString()